# How to add jQuery to website

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web application. In the head of site master, I write this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

and when I create project, the script file is added, but when I use $ function, I get undefined error.

What should I do?

Comment: What function you are writing for javascript ?

Comment: I use $ .but it is undefined Realy I need it

Comment: Can you post exact error? Also, try replacing "<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>" as source. If path is incorrect, this will resolve it. Also using cdn files increases option of using cached file instead of downloading every time.

Comment: Use firebug and move it to page header to see if jquery is loaded properly. I mean its will tell you whether the path you have stated for jquery is right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I (and almost every other developer) do:

[image]

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //write jquery code 


    });
 </script>
 </head>
```

Or alternatively you can directly refer your custom JS beneath the jQuery reference.

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/Your_Custom_JS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Side Note

This is the preferred way of writing code because you will segregate from UI layer and also, Chrome browser does not support inline debugging.